# Get the file name and save in a var

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
          url: url,
          dataType: 'json',
          done: function (e, data) {
              $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                  $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files'); 
                  // the previuous line line print the name of the file
                  file_name = ¿?
                  document.getElementById("f1").value = file_name;
              });
          },
```

This code works fine, but I need the name of the file printed by the line:

```
$('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
```

and save this file name in a variable -> file_name to set value in f1 element.

¿How can get this name? Im javascript beginner.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the value of `file.name`?

Comment: Try this : file_name = file.name;

Comment: Perfect. Solved!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that many ways, but I can tell you two simplest ways to achieve what you are looking for.

1. you can assign `file_name = $('#files').text();`.
2. you can assign `file_name = file.propertyName;` "propertyName" can be the property which holds the name of the file.

Please let me know which one helpful for you.